# Insert var multiplied by a number into mongo db

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to insert a variable multiplied by several floating point numbers into a meteor collection like this and use it in a reactive table. It is not working and I don't know if I can even do this. here is my code:

```
Template.cover.events({
    'submit .js-ftp-submit': function(event) {
        console.log("Clicked");
        var ftp, lthr;
        ftp = event.target.ftp.value;
        lthr = event.target.lthr.value;
        console.log("ftp: " + ftp + " lthr :  " + lthr);

        if (Meteor.user()) {
            Zones.insert({
                end_pwr_1: ftp * .56,
                end_pwr_2: ftp * .75,
                end_hr_1: lthr * .80,
                end_hr_2: lthr * .90,
                temp_pwr_1: ftp * .76,
                temp_pwr_2: ftp * .85,
                temp_lthr_1: lthr * .91,
                temp_lthr_2: lthr * .95,
                ss_pwr_1: ftp * .86,
                ss_pwr_2: ftp * .95,
                ss_lthr_1: lthr * .96,
                ss_lthr_2: lthr * .99,
                thresh_pwr_1: ftp * .96,
                thresh_pwr_2: ftp * 1.05,
                thresh_lthr_1: lthr * 1,
                thresh_lthr_2: lthr * 1.02,
                vo2_pwr_1: ftp * 1.06,
                vo2_pwr_2: ftp * 1.20,
                vo2_lthr_1: lthr * 1.03,
                vo2_lthr_2: lthr * 1.06,
                anaerobic_pwr_1: ftp * 1.21,
                anaerobic_pwr_2: ftp * 1.50,
                np_pwr_1: "over",
                np_pwr_2: ftp * 1.51
            });
        }

    }


});
```

can I even try to insert into the db by multiplying the variable?
The console logs the 2 variable ok but nothing in the table.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a terrible problem description. It doesn't work _how_? Any errors?

Comment: no errors. I just get 'undefined' when I do a Zones.findOne() in the console. so I am assuming it is not working. I am new to programming.

Comment: Then, perhaps, `Meteor.user()` returns  falsy value, so your insert never runs.

Comment: @OscarDulzaides what about the `autopublish` package? Have you checked the Zones collection in the terminal (run `meteor mongo` then `db.Zones.find()` - it may be that you haven't published / subscribed to the collection in the client which is why nothing is coming up in the browser console

Comment: autopublish was indeed commented out. after uncommenting the data is getting inserted into the collection. @SergioTulentsev Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example solution to your problem:

```
var ftp = (value here);
     Zones.insert({
            "end_pwr_1": ftp * .56,
            "end_pwr_2": ftp * .75
          });
```

For me it works perfectly, just make sure you have allowed insert, if insecure package is removed. Obviously, the answer to the question can you insert by multiplying is: "yes".

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to delve into this further. Insecure has not been removed but yet I get nothing in the table. I will research this further as something else is preventing me from inserting these values. I keep getting undefined from the console when I do a findOne().